# android notification of the date that you select user

Tags: java, android, datetime, datepicker, notifications

I need to write an app in `Android` and I want to give user the name and date of notification, the data is saved in `SQLite`, but I do not know how to do that notification was a particular date which shall make the user in the `DatePicker`. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: ok, but I do not know exactly how to do to run as a notification when then give the user the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Datepicker online or from app?
You said name and date are stored in sqlite so it should be on the mobile. 
There are several ways to handle something.

Example:
Create DB entry with min. id,date,time.
Ask the database for today's date.
Is there a Match?
If so, get the time of this database id.
Create a notification whith this time for today.

Was this helpful?

Edit: 
If u got a hit in your activity, u need to broadcast it internaly to the system. Andoid works like: your app tells system, hello i got an file, type is xxx, who want to handle it?
Different vendors got different apps, normally everyone can handle the standard request.
How to call other apps is well documented on Android developing site.
Notice, sry for spelling writting from my swissphone and it tries to autocorrects everything :)

Comment: user3367946 please contact us, will show you exactly what I mean. allegro191@o2.pl

Comment: Sent u a mail. Maybe this will interest u too it was quite new when i was studiing and it helped me getting into android. some free lessons from google about how with android https://de.udacity.com/